# How do I call an API with Java/Ruby and use it on my Ionic 3 mobile app?

Tags: java, ruby, angular, http, ionic-framework

I have been trying to access a RESTful API for an app that I am currently building and I have been coming across countless CORS issues.

I eventually emailed the site that I am using the API from and he told me they do not support CORS and to call the API using a server side language. He also told me that a Ruby Gem exists.

I have some basic experience in Java and Ruby, however I can not find any help on how I can use either to access an API that I can use in my Ionic app.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit server requests to the API, but not requests through a web browser because of CORS, so what you can do is essentially proxy requests through a server you run. For instance, your Ionic app will send a request to your server, which will then submit an appropriate request to the API and then an appropriate response to your Ionic app.

Any web library can handle communicating with the API, using HTTP requests. For ruby things like Httparty, the included Net::HTTP library, or the gem the API owner mentions could all work. In java it looks like you can use HttpUrlConnection to make simple http requests.